# CSS and JS files not loading, MAMP Server

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, mamp, mime

I am having an issue where some CSS and JS files are not loading on a MAMP server running locally.  The files are part of a www directory for a Cordova / PhoneGap app.  When I try to view the site locally from a desktop browser I have some issues with certain CSS and JS not loading (see image).  If I move the CSS to the root and load from a index.php page there it loads fine.

Not sure if that is a server configuration issue (MIME types) or something peculiar to the server config, or that fact that it is a Cordova project.

Thanks.

[image: Network Log]

Comment: It says 404, not found. Are you sure about the URL?

Comment: Check out the post here: http://racingtadpole.com/blog/25/. It says that rather than using the localhost:8888 that you use the actual ip address, maybe that's why your assets aren't loading.

Comment: Load your Phonegap app from its server, not MAMP: http://phonegap.com/getstarted/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly why, but the fix appears to have been loading the non-minified versions of my jQuery Mobile libraries.  I am using 1.4.5 versions.  Not sure if the source from Jquery was corrupted somehow of if they can altered when I unzipped the package.